# Law of total expectation: how to relate $E(X) = E(E(X|Y))$ to $E(X) = \sum_i E(X|A_i)P(A_i)$?

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

Below is the definition of the law of total expectation from [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation).

[image]

The first equation states that for any $X, Y$ on the same probability space, then
\begin{equation}
E(X) = E(E(X|Y))
\end{equation}

It then states that one special case is

\begin{equation}
E(X) = \sum_i E(X|A_i)P(A_i)
\end{equation}
if $\{A_i\}_i$ is a finite or countable partition of the sample space.

The way that the second equation is prefaced by "one special case.." leads me to think that it is a special case of the first equation.

**My question is: how can one relate $E(X) = E(E(X|Y))$ to $E(X) = \sum_i E(X|A_i)P(A_i)$?**

That is, if I define $Y = \{A_i\}_{i=1}^{n}$ as the set of partitions on the sample space, is the following correct?
$$E(X) = E(E(X|Y)) = \sum_i E(X|A_i)P(A_i)$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the law of total expectation $E(E(X | Y) ) = E(X)$  is more general, it makes sense to show how this implies $E(X) = \sum_{i = 1}^n E(X | A_i)P(A_i)$.

Consider $Y_i = I_{A_i}$ using $\displaystyle \Omega = \dot{\cup}_{i =1}^n A_i$ it follows that $ P \left( \sum_{i =1}^n Y_i = 1 \right) = 1$.  Then you have

\begin{align}
 E(X)  & = \sum_{i=1}^n E(X Y_i) \\ 
       & = \sum_{i=1}^n E(E(X Y_i | Y_i)) \\
       & = \sum_{i=1}^n E(X Y_i | Y_i = 1) P(Y_i =1) + E(X Y_i | Y_i = 0) P(Y_i = 0)     \\
       & = \sum_{i=1}^n E( X  | Y_i = 1) P(Y_i =1) + E( 0 |Y_i = 0) P(Y_i = 0) \\
       & = \sum_{i=1}^n E( X  | A_i) P(A_i). 
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks. Is it correct to add one last line to the derivation above: i.e., $\sum_{i=1}^n E(X|A_i)P(A_i) = E(E(X|Y))$

Comment: That is just because $E(X) = E(E(X|Y))$.